# How to remove duplicate entries from MySql database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I had heavy SQL dump of a table. I used bigdump lib to import it in MySql database on my server. 
Although it worked fine, but now I have duplicated entries in that table.
same table on local server has 8 * 10<sup>5</sup> records but on server it has 15 * 10<sup>5</sup> records.

Can you suggest me a query to delete duplicate entries from this table?
Here is my table structure.

[image]

Table name is : techdata_products

**P.S. This table does not have any primary key.**

Comment: Would recommend to copy un-duplicated list to another table  `select distinct * from techdata_products into temp_techdata_products;`

Comment: Are the 'dupe' records exact copies of each other (all fields equal) or are only SOME of the fields equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL is not my strong point but I think you can export the result of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table;
```

And then, create a new table and import your results.

Answer (score 2):

First starters why do you have no primary key? You could have simply made that id field that auto increments a primary key to prevent duplicates. My suggestion would be to create a new table and do a

Select Distinct * from table and put the results into a new table that has a primary key

Comment: well mate, it has 15 lac records and MySql script would not work smoothly for it.

Comment: can you provide an example of what your dupe records look like? That would help give a better understanding of how to write the script.

Comment: also have you tried writing any delete queries that you think could work or have tested in a dev environment but might just need tweaking?